# best way to get something like GCC -Wconversion but more usable?

Tags: c, gcc

Without -Wconversion the compiler doesn't warn for this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void foofunc (uint8_t arg) { printf ("arg: %i\n", arg); }
uint32_t biggie = 42000;
int main (void) { foofunc (biggie); return 0; }
```

Even with -Wall and -Wextra the compiler silently builds that program which prints 16 which we all know is wrong :)

But with -Wconversion you have to write stuff like this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void foofunc (uint8_t arg) { printf ("arg: %i\n", arg); }
uint8_t littlevar = 42; ;
int main (void) { foofunc ((uint8_t) (littlevar + 1)); return 0; }
```

I guess that last happens because the summands somehow get turned into int before the addition.  Using UINT8_C(1) doesn't fix it anyway.  And then there are lots of casts for strings etc.

Is there some middle way I'm missing out on that would catch the completely obtuse pass of a uint32_t to a uint8_t while not requiring quite so much noisy casting elsewhere?

Comment: What if the value of `littlevar` were 255? Would you want to be warned or not?

Comment: @FredLarson compiler will not warn runtime :)

Comment: @0___________: Oh, I know.

Comment: @FredLarson there should be a warning `**Warning** Style. Properly format your code`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the cast seems unnecessary to me in the second example. `foofunc(littlevar + 1)` works just fine without warning. Case in point: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5YGsM3Txn

Comment: @Frank ah so it does that was not the case for GCC 7.3.0 (which I'm stuck on).  So maybe there wasn't any actual promotion happening.  But isn't 1 an int literal by default so littlevar should promote to int then the conversion back to uint8_t trigger the warning?  I would have thought UINT8_C(1) would be needed

Comment: @FredLarson yeah I would want to be warned.  I realize what I'm wishing for here is somewhat ill-defined but it still seems desirable, whatever it might be :)

Comment: Although compilers have gotten better in the last few years, they tend to accept compliant code without warnings. Use a linter for deeper inspection. -- You will not find all errors by static analysis, only the apparent ones. There is no way around thoroughly testing.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, `static void foofunc (uint8_t arg) { printf ("arg: %i\n", arg); }` is strictly speaking wrong. You should be using `PRIu8` not `%i`.

> the compiler silently builds that program which prints 16 which we all know is wrong

No, neither the compiler nor another programmer knows that it is wrong. Truncating a large integer to a small one can be a valid use-case, though preferably the conversion should be explicit, by a cast or by assignment to a temporary variable.

> But with -Wconversion you have to write stuff like this

The most obvious correction of your code would be `foofunc ((uint8_t)biggie)` and that has nothing to do with the compiler. It does however silence `-Wconversion` on newer gcc versions.

> I guess that last happens because the summands somehow get turned into int before the addition

Yes due through "the usual arithmetic conversions" you get an implicit int conversion, which is exactly the kind of subtle C language defect stuff that you want warnings about. Instead of unsigned 8 you get a large signed type.

---

Overall, `-Wconversion` isn't great, it comes with a lot of false positives. It's not an option you should normally use, but rather one you should activate temporary during code review etc.

These kind of issues are normally found with external static analysis tools and not the compiler. One example is clang-tidy, but there are lots of commercial ones as well.